# Create Azure AKS with Managed Identity using Terraform gives AutoUpgradePreview not enabled error

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to create an AKS cluster with managed identity using Terraform. This is my code so far, pretty basic and standard from a few documentation and blog posts I found online.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.79.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  use_msi = true
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "prod_test"
  location = "northeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
  name                = "prod_test_cluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "weak"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = "4"
    vm_size    = "standard_ds3_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

And this is the error message that I can't come around to a solution. Any thoughts on it?

```sh
Error: creating Managed Kubernetes Cluster "prod_test_cluster" (Resource Group "prod_test"): containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="Feature Microsoft.ContainerService/AutoUpgradePreview is not enabled. Please see https://aka.ms/aks/previews for how to enable features."
│ 
│   with azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster,
│   on main.tf line 19, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster":
│   19: resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
│
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it on my environment and faced the same issue as you can see below:

[image]

- So, to give a description on the issue the `AutoChannelUpgrade` went
  to public preview on August 2021. And as per the `terraform azurerm provider 2.79.0` , it bydefault passes that value to none in the
  backend but as we have not registered for the feature it fails giving
  the error `Feature Microsoft.ContainerService/AutoUpgradePreview is not enabled`.
- To confirm you don't have the feature registered you can use the
  below command :

  ```
  az feature show -n AutoUpgradePreview --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService
  ```

  You will see it not registered as below:

  [image]

---

Now to overcome this you can try two solutions as given below:

1. You can try using `terraform azurerm provider 2.78.0` instead of `2.79.1`.
2. Other solution will be to register for the feature and then you can
   use the same code that you are using .

   **You can follow the below steps:**

> - You can use below command to register the feature (it will take around 5
>   mins to get registered) :
>
>   ```
>   az login --identity 
>   az feature register --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService -n AutoUpgradePreview
>   ```
> - After the above is done you can check the registration stauts with below command :
>
>   ```
>   az feature registration show --provider-namespace Microsoft.ContainerService -n AutoUpgradePreview
>   ```
>
>   [image]
> - After the feature status becomes registered you can do a terraform apply to your code .
>
>   I tested it using the below code on my VM:
>
>   ```
>   provider "azurerm" {
>   features {}
>   subscription_id = "948d4068-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-e00a844e059b"
>   tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-2d7cd011db47"
>   use_msi = true
>   }
>
>   resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
>   name     = "terraformtestansuman"
>   location = "west us 2"
>   }
>
>   resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
>   name                = "prod_test_cluster"
>   location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
>   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
>   dns_prefix          = "weak"
>
>   default_node_pool {
>   name       = "default"
>   node_count = "4"
>   vm_size    = "standard_ds3_v2"
>   }
>   identity {
>   type = "SystemAssigned"
>   }
>   }
>   ```
>
>   **Outputs:**
>   [image]
>
>   [image]

**Reference:**

[Github Issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli)

[Install Azure CLI if not installed on the VM using Microsoft Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: I had read about the update and I tried downgrading to version 2.78.0 but for some reason it also didn't work. However you solution 2) worked like a charm! Thank you so much for the time and effort to give this descriptive response!

Comment: Glad to be of help!!

Comment: @AnsumanBa-MT do you usually create a managed identity for each resource group?

Comment: hello @everspader, I usually use my credentials for terraform authentication using az login. For using terraform on a VM I use a system managed identity for that VM and set role as contributor or owner on subscription . so that i don't have to assign roles for that msi in every resource group.

Comment: This might be a silly question but why use a VM with Terraform here to provision a new cluster?

Comment: no not specifically for provisioning a new cluster ..for using a VM which has terraform like your local machine and system managed identity by default .. if you want to use your local machine and managed identity then i guess you can login with `az login --identity -u /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/myID`

Comment: and to use that managed identity in a specific rg to be used for subscription then assign the same owner/contributor role to subscription . so that you can use any resource group  in your subscription